# Sublime Text Plugin - How can I get the comment block type of the current syntax

Tags: comments, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Sublime Text and I would like to get the characters to use to add a comment with the current syntax of the document.

e.g.

- Python       -> `#`
- PHP -> `//`
- C -> `//`
- C++ -> `//`
- .ini         -> `;`
- ...

Of course, I could use

```
view.run_command('toggle_comment', {'block': True})
```

But I DON'T want to just add a comment, I want to know the characters that I should use...

Any ideas?

> I had a look in this [documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands), but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `view.meta_info('shellVariables', 0)` to get an array of the [`shellVariables`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/comments.html#md-comments-shellvariables) that are defined for the current document's syntax.

(The second argument, where I specified `0`, represents the position ([a.k.a point in official terminology](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#type-point)) in the view to interrogate, which can be useful for views containing embedded syntaxes i.e. PHP/HTML/JS)

---

**Examples:**

On a Python file it returns:

```
[{'name': 'TM_COMMENT_START', 'value': '# '}, {'name': 'TM_LINE_TERMINATOR', 'value': ':'}]
```

On an XML file it returns:

```
[{'name': 'TM_COMMENT_END', 'value': ' -->'}, {'name': 'TM_COMMENT_START', 'value': '<!-- '}]
```

On a JavaScript file:

```
[{'name': 'TM_COMMENT_END_2', 'value': '*/'}, {'name': 'TM_COMMENT_START', 'value': '// '}, {'name': 'TM_COMMENT_START_2', 'value': '/*'}]
```

---

As you can see, the relevant dictionary item in the array has a `name` of `TM_COMMENT_START`, and for block comments, there will also be a `TM_COMMENT_END`. Syntaxes like JavaScript that support single line comments and block comments can also have the same names with an `_2` suffix.

---

Therefore, your code to get the characters to begin a comment could look like:

```
comment_characters = [var['value'] for var in view.meta_info('shellVariables', 0) if var['name'] == 'TM_COMMENT_START'][0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This is strange  `next(iter(view.meta_info('shellVariables', 0)), lambda check: check['name'] == 'TM_COMMENT_START')['value']` returns **TM_COMMENT_END**

Comment: that is indeed strange - which syntax is that on?

Comment: I tested `PHP : */` and `HTML: -->`

Comment: okay, I'm going to change my advice to this instead: `comment_characters = [var['value'] for var in view.meta_info('shellVariables', 0) if var['name'] == 'TM_COMMENT_START'][0]`, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I've [logged an issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1437) to ask for this `meta_info` method to be added to the official documentation :)

Comment: Good idea! I added a '+1'